# Striping or Removing quotations within a string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm attempting to create a pig-latin translation program. It is part of the 100 projects on GitHub I am working through. I do not like to check solutions before I have given it a real effort.

Here is the code I have at the moment, and it does complete the translation, the problem though is that it outputs the translation with some unsightly quotes around the replaced letter.

```
words = raw_input("Enter some text to translate to pig latin: ")
print "You entered: ", words

#Now I need to break apart the words into a list
words = words.split(' ')

#Now words is a list, so I can manipulate each one using a loop

for i in words:
    if len(i) >= 3: #I only want to translate words greater than 3 characters
        i = i + "%ray" % (i[0]) #The magical translator!
        i = i[1:] #I want to print the translation, but without the first letter
        print i.strip("'")
```

When I run this program I get this result:

```
You entered: hello world
ello'h'ay
orld'w'ay
```

I don't know how to strip the quotations out of my translated words. I think I'll use a .join command next to recreate the translated sentence, but I'm at a roadblock right now.

I have tried:

```
i = i.strip("'")
```

but that did not work either.
Thanks!

Comment: Why use `"%ray"` in the first place? Why not just do `i = i + i[0] + "ay"`?

Comment: Did you see [this other post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)                                                            How about:

>>> 'hello world'[::-1]
'dlrow olleh'
This is extended slice syntax. It works by doing [begin:end:step] - by leaving begin and end off and specifying a step of -1, it reverses a string.

Comment: @Kevin both methods do exactly the same thing?

Comment: @chad Not sure what you're post is referencing at all. I'm not asking about reversing strings, I did that project yesterday.

Comment: @HarrisonBoles, are you asking me? I think the answer is, "no, they do not do the same thing". `print i[0]` prints `h`, and `print "%r" % i[0]` prints `'h'`.

Comment: @Kevin that is true, but I was using %r incorrectly, once changed to %s it works exactly the same - it was from the answer I marked correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to replace anything. It's the '%r' in the format string that is causing the problem.

Change this:

```
i = i + "%ray" % (i[0])
```

Into this:

```
i = i + "%say" % (i[0])
```

...and it will all be fine.

Comment: This does work and is the best answer I think. I'll go lookup the differences between %r %d and %s

Answer (score 1):

If the characters you want to remove aren't at the ends of the string, then `str.strip` won't work.

Instead, you should be using [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) here:

```
print i.replace("'", "")
```

See a demonstration:

```
>>> 'aba'.strip('b')
'aba'
>>> 'aba'.replace('b', '')
'aa'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.strip()` strips the margins of the string. Use `.replace("'")` instead

```
for i in words:
    if len(i) >= 3:
        i = i + "%ray" % (i[0])
        i = i[1:]
        print i.replace("'")
```

Output:

```
You entered: hello world
ellohay
orldway
```